# Can a single Raspberry Pi serve as both a pi-hole and media server?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pihole

I need to add three functions to my home network:

- pi-hole
- media server (for music and video content)
- NAS (for shared storage)

Can a single Raspberry Pi play all those roles?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes it is possible but the performance of your media player and NAS may not be superb depending on load.

Pi-hole runs fine on a pi (hence the name) and has very little CPU or storage requirements. The media player and NAS will depend obviously on storage - an external SSD would be best but a) this would be over USB and b) would also be powered by same USB.

You could also put Docker on the Pi but now you're definitely stretching its capabilities.

Comment: Why would I run docker on the pi? (I think the pi can run all three concurrently, what benefit to put one or more piece in docker?)

Comment: Exactly. I'm not sure what distro pi-hole is based on (I run it in a Docker). The NAS and/or media server might not be available or working on that distro - Docker allows you to run anything available on your platform regardless of distro.